# C++ Allocation of incomplete type

Tags: c++, allocation

I'm tring to create Card and Deck classes but I'm getting an error message that says

Allocation of incomplete type 'Card'

The problem is happening in Deck::Deck() of Deck.cpp

//
//Deck.h

```
#ifndef JS_DECK_H
#define JS_DECK_H

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

//forward declaration
class Card;

namespace JS {
    class Deck {

    public:
        Deck();
    private:
        vector<Card *>cards;
    };

}

#endif
```

//
//Deck.cpp

```
#include "Deck.h"

using namespace JS;

Deck::Deck(){

    for(int suit = 0; suit < 4; suit++){
        for(int rank = 1; rank < 14; rank++){

            cards.push_back(new Card(rank, suit));//allocation of incomplete type 'Card'
        }
    }
}
```

//
//Card.h

```
#ifndef JS_CARD_H
#define JS_CARD_H

#include <ostream>
using std::ostream;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

namespace JS {
    class Card {

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Card &rhs);

    public:
        enum Suit { DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES, CLUBS };
        enum Rank { ACE = 1, JACK = 11, QUEEN = 12, KING = 13 };

        Card(int rank, int suit) : rank(rank), suit(suit){}

        string getRank() const;
        string getSuit() const;
        int getRankValue() const;

        int operator+(const Card& rhs);
        void displayCard(const Card &rhs);

    private:
        int rank;
        int suit;
    };

}

#endif
```

Comment: I suggest using a vector of `Card`, not `Card *`.

Comment: You only declared card, but didn't implement it in that scope

Comment: A warning: `using namespace JS;` in "Deck.cpp" doesn't add your definition of `Deck::Deck` to the namespace. You need the `namespace JS` and brackets there as well. You should also have your forward declaration of `Card` *inside* the namespace.

Comment: THANK YOU molbdnil, moving the forward declaration inside of the namespace did it...  I also had to add Card.h to the Deck.cpp like Joachim pointed out  THANKS everyone again

Answer (score 14):

In the implementation of `Deck` (i.e. the `Deck.cpp` file) you need the *full* definition of `Card` to be able to allocate objects of that type. So the solution is simply to include `Card.h` in `Deck.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks, i also had to move the forward declaration in Deck.h inside of the namespace

Comment: I would like to congratulate to the guys who chose "Allocation of incomplete type Card" over "Card header not found".

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to use a "move" operator? You can't just push the newly allocated memory onto the stack, it will be deleted by the end of scope. I am refering to this:

```
cards.push_back(new Card(rank, suit));
```